# PHP Twitter OAuth

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to make the registration and authorization of users on your site through twitter oauth. And I have problem.

I am using http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth PHP.

In this code, the authorization pass by adding the token to the session. But how can I make sure that data is added to the cookie?

How to make sure that the user is logged on to my site using a tweeter (for half a year in the cookie). And how can I check whether the user entered the site at all?

I hope I explained this properly (

Comment: I use the same library. not sure what you are asking though. you shouldnt be storing their tokens in a cookie, you must keep it secure in a session or database only on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend checking out the Zend_Service_Twitter and Zend_Oauth libraries.  I'm using them for twitter functionality myself and they work great.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html